# text field that only allow and number and dash and also accepts ctrl commands

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode != 45 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

i have been using this function but its does not allow ctrl + commands.
like ctrl + a , ctrl + c

Comment: because you have disabled it with `return false;` isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you want to do something like this to sort it out:

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = evt.which || event.keyCode;
    if (!evt.ctrlKey && charCode != 45 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

just check if ctrlKey is pressed, if do then only in conjunction with `!evt.ctrlKey` disable it.